# How to differenciate duplicate elements through jaxb bindings.xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, duplicates

I have to deal with an xsd schema to generate the java code through jaxb and there is two elements withe same name in one of the sequence. This is causing troubles and i have come to use bindings.xml to differrenciate both elements.

My problem is that i can not manage to pinpoint one single element for this purpose, it is targetting the element i want plus another element from another compleType.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xs:schema  
    xmlns="urn:IETF:metadata:2005:FLUTE:FDT"  
    xmlns:fl="urn:IETF:metadata:2005:FLUTE:FDT"  
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:mbms2005="urn:3GPP:metadata:2005:MBMS:FLUTE:FDT" 
    xmlns:mbms2007="urn:3GPP:metadata:2007:MBMS:FLUTE:FDT" 
    xmlns:mbms2008="urn:3GPP:metadata:2008:MBMS:FLUTE:FDT_ext" 
    xmlns:mbms2009="urn:3GPP:metadata:2009:MBMS:FLUTE:FDT_ext" 
    xmlns:mbms2012="urn:3GPP:metadata:2012:MBMS:FLUTE:FDT" 
    xmlns:sv="urn:3gpp:metadata:2009:MBMS:schemaVersion" 
    targetNamespace="urn:IETF:metadata:2005:FLUTE:FDT"  
    elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    version="2"> 
    <xs:import namespace="urn:3GPP:metadata:2005:MBMS:FLUTE:FDT" 
                schemaLocation="FLUTE-FDT-3GPP-2005-Extensions.xsd"/> 
    <xs:import namespace="urn:3GPP:metadata:2007:MBMS:FLUTE:FDT"  
                schemaLocation="FLUTE-FDT-3GPP-2007-Extensions.xsd"/> 
    <xs:import namespace="urn:3GPP:metadata:2008:MBMS:FLUTE:FDT_ext"  
                schemaLocation="FLUTE-FDT-3GPP-2008-Extensions.xsd"/> 
    <xs:import namespace="urn:3GPP:metadata:2009:MBMS:FLUTE:FDT_ext"  
                schemaLocation="FLUTE-FDT-3GPP-2009-Extensions.xsd"/> 
    <xs:import namespace="urn:3GPP:metadata:2012:MBMS:FLUTE:FDT"  
                schemaLocation="FLUTE-FDT-3GPP-2012-Extensions.xsd"/> 
    <xs:import namespace="urn:3gpp:metadata:2009:MBMS:schemaVersion"  
                schemaLocation="schema-version.xsd"/> 
    <xs:element name="FDT-Instance" type="FDT-InstanceType"/> 
    <xs:complexType name="FDT-InstanceType"> 
        <xs:sequence> 
            <xs:element name="File" type="FileType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
            <xs:element ref="sv:schemaVersion"/>        
            <xs:element ref="mbms2012:Base-URL-1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
            <xs:element ref="mbms2012:Base-URL-2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>          
            <xs:element ref="sv:delimiter"/>         
            <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
            <xs:element name="Group" type="mbms2005:groupIdType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
            <xs:element name="MBMS-Session-Identity-Expiry" type="mbms2005:MBMS-Session-Identity-Expiry-Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
        </xs:sequence> 
        <xs:attribute name="Expires" type="xs:string" use="required"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="Complete" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="Content-Type" type="xs:string" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="Content-Encoding" type="xs:string" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-FEC-Encoding-ID" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-FEC-Instance-ID" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-Maximum-Source-Block-Length" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-Encoding-Symbol-Length" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-Max-Number-of-Encoding-Symbols" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-Scheme-Specific-Info" type="xs:base64Binary" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute ref="mbms2008:FullFDT" use="optional" default="false"/> 
        <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/> 
    </xs:complexType> 
    <xs:complexType name="FileType"> 
        <xs:sequence> 
            <xs:element ref="mbms2007:Cache-Control" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="sv:delimiter"/>        
            <xs:element ref="mbms2012:Alternate-Content-Location-1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
            <xs:element ref="mbms2012:Alternate-Content-Location-2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
            <xs:element ref="sv:delimiter"/>         
            <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
            <xs:element name="Group" type="mbms2005:groupIdType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
            <xs:element name="MBMS-Session-Identity" type="mbms2005:MBMS-Session-Identity-Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> 
        </xs:sequence> 
        <xs:attribute name="Content-Location" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="TOI" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="Content-Length" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="Transfer-Length" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="Content-Type" type="xs:string" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="Content-Encoding" type="xs:string" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="Content-MD5" type="xs:base64Binary" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-FEC-Encoding-ID" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-FEC-Instance-ID" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-Maximum-Source-Block-Length" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-Encoding-Symbol-Length" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-Max-Number-of-Encoding-Symbols" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute name="FEC-OTI-Scheme-Specific-Info" type="xs:base64Binary" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute ref="mbms2009:Decryption-KEY-URI" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:attribute ref="mbms2012:FEC-Redundancy-Level" use="optional"/> 
        <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/> 
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:schema>
```

Here is my bindings.xml

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="FLUTE-FDT-3GPP-2005-Extensions.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='MBMS-Session-Identity-Expiry-Type']">
        <jxb:bindings node=".//xsd:attribute[@name='value']">
            <jxb:property name="requiredValue"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mbms-flute-release11.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='FileType']">
        <jxb:bindings multiple="true" node="//xs:element[2]">
            <jxb:property name="delimiter1"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

As a result, the first delimiter element is correctly renamed to delimiter1, but the schemaVersion element is also renamed to delimiter1!

Any suggestion on what is wrong?

## **EDIT 1**

After using `@ref` as suggested by my bindings.xml looks like this :

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="FLUTE-FDT-3GPP-2005-Extensions.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='MBMS-Session-Identity-Expiry-Type']">
            <jxb:bindings node=".//xsd:attribute[@name='value']">
                <jxb:property name="requiredValue"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mbms-flute-release11.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='FileType']">
            <jxb:bindings multiple="true" node="//xs:element[@ref='sv:delimiter'][1]">
                <jxb:property name="delimiter1"/>
            </jxb:bindings> 
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@ref='sv:delimiter'][2]">
                <jxb:property name="delimiter2"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Now it renames all occurernces of `sv:delimiter` (3 in the document) instead of only those within FileType complexe type.
It is better than before but i'd like to be able to only rename selected elements not all if possible.

## **Solution**

Thanks to Xstian, this is the solution that is working :

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="FLUTE-FDT-3GPP-2005-Extensions.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='MBMS-Session-Identity-Expiry-Type']">
            <jxb:bindings node=".//xsd:attribute[@name='value']">
                <jxb:property name="requiredValue"/>
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mbms-flute-release11.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='FileType']//xs:element[@ref='sv:delimiter'][1]">
                <jxb:property name="delimiter1"/>
            </jxb:bindings> 
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='FileType']//xs:element[@ref='sv:delimiter'][2]">
                <jxb:property name="delimiter2"/>
            </jxb:bindings> 
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use for example

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mbms-flute-release11.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='FileType']">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@ref='mbms2012:Alternate-Content-Location-1']">
            <jxb:property name="delimiter1"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

or

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mbms-flute-release11.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='FileType']//xs:element[@ref='mbms2012:Alternate-Content-Location-1']">
          <jxb:property name="delimiter1"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: It does not seems to work :
`[ERROR] compiler was unable to honor this property customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
  line 8 of file:/C:/projects/dev/Server/trunk/Jaxb/FDT/release11/bindings.xml`

Comment: Yes, it is an example because i don't understand which element you want redefine, Anyway you can use `@ref=` to identify the correct `xs:element`

Comment: The elements to redifine are the `sv:delimiter` elements just above and below `mbms2012:Alternate-Content-Location-1`.
Using `@ref` with positional parameter seems to work for the second but it is still causing issues with the first one. I have edited my question with details.

Comment: You should remove `multiple="true"`, probably xpath returns more than one nodes.

Comment: removing `multiple=true` results in this error `[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//xs:element[@ref='sv:delimiter'][1]" results in too many (2) target nodes`

Comment: Perfect, should be simple.. use only one `<jxb:bindings` using the entire xpath like `//xs:complexType[@name='FileType']//xs:element[@ref='sv:delimiter'][1]` I adding an example above in the answer

Comment: That's it! It is giving the exact output i am expecting.
Thank you.