# JAXB Binding file: How to rename the first element of a node?

Tags: xsd, jaxb, jaxb2, xjc

I am trying to generate Java classes from XSD file with XJC.

In my XSD file, there is something like:

```
<xs:complexType name="SomeNode">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="FOO" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="BAR" minOccurs="0"/> 
    <xs:element name="BAZ" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="BAR" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

XJC can't parse correctly the XML files, because there are 2 non-consecutive `BAR` elements (ie. `getBAR()` is ambiguous). So I need to rename the first `BAR` element in the `SomeNode` with a binding file. Something like this:

```
<bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='SomeNode']">
    <!-- Here I need to get only the first element -->
    <bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Bar']">
        <class name="FirstBar"/>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

How to get the first element of a node in my binding file?

Comment: More or less you have the same problem [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35205687/3364187).

Comment: Note I can't edit the XSD file.

Comment: You have a big problem if you cannot change that XSD. You cannot have the same name also using external bindings. [See here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#concepts-nameSymbolSpaces)

Comment: @Xstian About your link: The first and and the second `BAR` element have the same reference. So I can't get them separately with `@ref`.